# Pre-processing of an image with OpenCV on Android for optimizing ocr accuracy

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I want to use OpenCV Library for Android in combine with tesseract ocr engine. I'm making ocr on an image with tess-two which is using leptonica for image processing. But as i'm seeing we need better pre-processing for having better accuracy on the results. As i searched the internet i found that OpenCv Library have some filters for image pre-processing. The problem is i don't know how to use them, which filters to use and in which order for OCR. Can somebody explain me with code-example? Thank you!

Else if there is another suggestion for pre-processing an image before giving it for ocr on tesseract engine tell me.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that Tesseract responds very well to binarized - or at least background subtracted - images.

Start with AdaptiveThreshold. Also look into PerspectiveTransform. These two are guaranteed to give you improved results if you apply them right.